# Null Pointer Exception with ArrayList

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

so I am playing around with some code and I am getting this error when I run it,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at VRSolution.findSavings(VRSolution.java:35)
    at VRTests.main(VRTests.java:22)
```

This is my code

```
public void testAlgo() {
    this.soln = new ArrayList<List<Customer>>();
    int max = this.prob.depot.c;
    int current = 0;
    ArrayList<Customer> route = null;
    for(Customer c:prob.customers){
        if(current <= max){
            route.add(c);
            current += c.c;
        }
        else {
            route = new ArrayList<Customer>();
            soln.add(route);
        }
    }
}
```

if anyone could help me understand why I am getting this It would be much appreciate thanks

Comment: what's `prob`? Can you paste the relevant code?

Comment: You are invoking `add` method on your `route` variable which was initialized to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

route.add(c); line may be called before arraylist initialization.
Probably this is your problem. So initialize route before adding an item to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
ArrayList<Customer> route = null;
```

and then this:

```
route.add(c);
```

If you try and invoke a method on a `null` reference, you get a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ArrayList<Customer> route = null;` by

```
List<Customer> route = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your list before you call it. Route is null in your case that's why you got the exception.

Try this:

```
   ArrayList<Customer> route = new ArrayList<>();
```